# Is there a way to initialize block_size in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I used code like

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 32
```

to determine block size for kernel function.

Is there any way to detect reasonable block size for kernel function at the time when program runs?

Comment: What do you mean by "reasonable block size"? Do you need to compute the optimal threads and blocks configuration at runtime?

Comment: Reasonable block size is for the performance. Yes, I need (near to) optimal threads and blocks configuration at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the kernel, the intrinsic variable gridDim contains the block size.  (It corresponds to special read-only registers in the hardware.)

It is 3D, so you have to write gridDim.x, grimDim.y, or grimDim.z.